# DrawableCompat.unwrap is not working pre Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, drawable, android-support-library, tint

I'm using DrawableCompat.wrap to set tint on drawables in pre Lollipop and it's working fine.
DrawableCompat.unwrap is not working pre Lollipop. 
I can't get the original drawable before the tint.

For example:

```
 if (v.isSelected()){
                Drawable normalDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample);
                Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(normalDrawable);
                DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.sample_color));
                imageButton.setImageDrawable(wrapDrawable);
 }else{
                Drawable normalDrawable = imageButton.getDrawable();
                Drawable unwrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.unwrap(normalDrawable);
                imageButton.setImageDrawable(unwrapDrawable);
 }
```

In pre lollipop devices DrawableCompact.unwrap returns the drawable with the tint and not the original one

Comment: Any news about this? Have you found a solution?

Comment: @chrisonline Nothing new. We aren't using this functionality because of this behaviour, which is unfortunate because it is a strong tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear the tint, call `DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable, null)`.

`Unwrap` isn't a destructive function, it's only there for you to get access to the original Drawable.

The following is an **example code**:

```
Drawable drawable = (Drawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.google_image);
if (condition) {
    drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.grey700));
    DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SCREEN);
    mImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
} else {
    drawable = DrawableCompat.unwrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(drawable, null);
    mLoginStatusGoogleImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
```

In **your case** the code should be:

```
if (v.isSelected()) {
    Drawable normalDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sample);
    Drawable wrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(normalDrawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.sample_color));
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrapDrawable, getResources().getColor(R.color.sample_color));
    imageButton.setImageDrawable(wrapDrawable);
} else {
    Drawable normalDrawable = imageButton.getDrawable();
    Drawable unwrapDrawable = DrawableCompat.unwrap(normalDrawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(unwrapDrawable, null);
    imageButton.setImageDrawable(unwrapDrawable);
}
```